# phoenix config dev.secret not being loaded

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have configured some settings at config/dev.secret.exs

```
use Mix.Config
config :rumbl, :wolfram, app_id: "someid"
```

And when I try to use it in another part of the code it looks like the variable is empty:

```
IO.puts app_id()
```

Or more specifically

```
  defp fetch_xml(query_str) do
    {:ok, {_, _, body}} = :httpc.request(
      String.to_char_list("http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query" <>
        "?appid=#{app_id()}" <>
        "&input=#{URI.encode(query_str)}&format=plaintext"))
    body
  end
```

Do I have to do anything specific to load that dev module when running iex -S mix shell or mix phoenix.server?

Comment: Can you confirm, at the end of you `config/dev.exs` you have line like: `import_config "dev.secret.exs"`, this will make the _secrets_ file to load. You might need to restart your server for Phoenix to pick this change

Comment: That is, wasnt importing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be default `dev.secrets.exs` is not loaded, to make it happen, you need to amend `config/dev.exs` and add this line at the end:

```
import_config "dev.secret.exs"
```

Comment: I have it down there, not the issue.